# How can I split a String into a multidimensional Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I think there are answers to a similar question already but I found my own way to do it:

```
String input = new String("word1,word2 word3,word4,word5,word6 word7,word8,word9");
String [] arrayString1D = input.split("|");
String [][] arrayString2D = new String[arrayString1D.length][];

for(int x = 0; x < arrayString1D.length; x++) {
        arrayString2D[x] = arrayString1D[x].split(" ");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayString2D));
//and it prints: [[word1, word2], [word3, word4, word5, word6], [word7, word8, word9]]
```

and that works fine. But I'm struggling with a 3dimensional Array.
My code so far:

```
String input = new String("word1,word2 word3,word4,word5,word6|word7,word8,word9 word10,word11|word7,word8,word9 word10,word11");

String [] arrayString1D = input.split("|");
String [][] arrayString2D = new String[arrayString1D.length][];
String [][][] arrayString3D = new String[arrayString2D.length][][];

for(int x = 0; x < arrayString1D.length; x++) {
    arrayString2D[x] = arrayString1D[x].split(" ");

    for(int y = 0; y < arrayString2D[x].length; y++) {
        arrayString3D[x][y] = arrayString2D[x][y].split(",");
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayString3D));
```

and I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`.
**Is it possible to do it my way or am I completly wrong?**

Comment: You are missing a `arrayString3D[x] = new String [arrayString2D[x].length][];`. All of the values in `arrayString3D` are `null`, so `arrayString3D[x][y]` causes NPE.

Comment: @Andreas Where should I put that? I get strange results if I do that... Every word is splittedinto chars.

Comment: That is because `|` is a special character in regex. You need to escape it: `split("\\|")`

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.
First one:

```
String [] arrayString1D = input.split("|");
```

In the above line, "|" is a metacharacter in regex. So that has to be escaped. The above line should change to

```
String[] arrayString1D = input.split("\\|");
```

Second issue:
While initializing the three dimensional array, it should be done like this

`String [][][] arrayString3D = new String[arrayString2D.length][][];`

With these two changes, i got the below output

> [[[word1, word2], [word3, word4, word5, word6], null], [[word7, word8, word9], [word10, word11], null], [[word7, word8, word9], [word10, word11], null]]

Comment: I wanted this output(without: null): [[[word1, word2], [word3, word4, word5, word6]], [[word7, word8, word9], [word10, word11]], [[word7, word8, word9], [word10, word11]]] And Andreas explained my mistakes below my question in a comment and it works. But thanks anyway!